# Knockout JS - Binding to array of observable Ints

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind a simple array of **integers** to an unordered list with inputs, like so:

ViewModel

```
self.amounts = ko.observableArray();
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    self.amounts.push(ko.observable(i));
}
```

HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: amounts">
    <li><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data"/></li>
</ul>
```

This produces the list with the inputs properly filled in with the numbers 0-4. However, when I change the value of any of the inputs the ViewModel does not get the new values.

If I use an array of simple objects as the observableArray, like so:

```
[{amt: 0}, {amt: 1}, {amt: 2}]
```

and adjust the HTML to bind the input to the "amt" property, then changing the values in the inputs does trigger changes in the ViewModel.

Is it possible to use an array of simple values and achieve two-way binding, without using a workaround that changes the original data model? If so, what am I doing wrong?

**edit:** this question is different than the one to which it has been marked as duplicate [Knockout JS - How to correctly bind an observableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510539/knockout-js-how-to-correctly-bind-an-observablearray),
it's about a special two-way binding case on simple type elements - *ints*, or *strings*.

Comment: Have you tried using an observableArray of ints instead of observable(int) ie: `self.amounts.push(i)` ?  I'm not positive, but I believe that should work.

Comment: I did try that, no luck. Also tried making the ints strings, which didn't work either.

Comment: The value binding needs to be passed a wrapped observable. I'm not sure how $data works exactly, but it may be that it will unwrap the observable before hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate question and my hunch was correct. $data will always unwrap observables, so you have to use an array of name, value object pairs instead.

See this question: [Knockout JS - How to correctly bind an observableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510539/knockout-js-how-to-correctly-bind-an-observablearray)

Comment: Thanks Michael, that clears things up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

$data is not going to work in this case. Instead, you can create an array of objects like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: amounts">
  <li>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: value" />
  </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: checkValues">Check</button>
```

.
.

```
var MyNumber = function (name, value) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.value = ko.observable(value);
};
var VM = function () {
  this.amounts = ko.observableArray();
  this.checkValues = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      console.log('amount = ' + vm.amounts()[i].value());
    }
  };
};
var vm = new VM();
vm.amounts().push(new MyNumber('a', 1));
vm.amounts().push(new MyNumber('b', 2));
vm.amounts().push(new MyNumber('c', 3));
vm.amounts().push(new MyNumber('d', 4));
vm.amounts().push(new MyNumber('e', 5));

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```