# Tracking changes - observable element in observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I need to edit an array of integers in a web application, using Javascript and Knockout.js. This array will be bound to text boxes, and whenever the value of any text box is changed, the array is updated. And when it gets updated, the sum of the elements is calculated.

This is my first try: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLs2A/0/. Its not working (the sum value is not update when typing a new value for any element). That's when I realized observableArray will only trigger the sum function after inserting or removing items.

```
<h4>Numbers</h4>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: numbers">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: $data"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
<span data-bind="text: sum"></span>

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numbers = ko.observableArray([
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function() {
        var items = self.numbers();
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(items[i]);
        }
        return total;
    });

    self.add = function() {
        var lastIndex = self.numbers().length - 1;
        var lastValue = self.numbers()[lastIndex];
        self.numbers.push(lastValue + 1);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

My next attempt was to make every element in the numbers array an observable (http://jsfiddle.net/ZLs2A/1/). It did not work again.

```
self.numbers = ko.observableArray([
    ko.observable(1),
    ko.observable(2),
    ko.observable(3)
]);
```

My last try was creating a new class (ArrayItem) to hold the value of the element inside a observable property. This time it worked! (http://jsfiddle.net/ZLs2A/3/)

```
<h4>Numbers</h4>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: numbers">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: value"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
<span data-bind="text: sum"></span>

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numbers = ko.observableArray([
        new ArrayItem(1),
        new ArrayItem(2),
        new ArrayItem(3)
    ]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function() {
        var items = self.numbers();
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(items[i].value());
        }
        return total;
    });

    self.add = function() {
        var lastIndex = self.numbers().length - 1;
        var lastItem = self.numbers()[lastIndex];
        var newValue = parseInt(lastItem.value()) + 1;
        self.numbers.push(new ArrayItem(newValue));
    }
}

function ArrayItem(value){
    var self = this;
    self.value = ko.observable(value);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

However, I didn't like to have to create this new class ArrayItem. **Is there any way to get rid of it, making the example work just having a observableArray of observable elements (like my second attempt)?**

Comment: The author of KO answered [this (possible duplicate?) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510539/knockout-js-how-to-correctly-bind-an-observablearray), basically in a similar way to your final version with an `ArrayItem` constructor (he just inlines that function). The answer is a year old, so something may have changed in the mean time... If it hasn't, it would seem you've already answered your own question.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning Breeze.js integration with Knockout.js which add Change Tracking amongst other things. http://www.breezejs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout will not track the value, but as a workaround you can use event keypress or change and update values yourself. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/ZLs2A/4/

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numbers = ko.observableArray([
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]);

    self.onChange = function(val, e){
        var el = e.srcElement;
        var newVal = parseInt(el.value);
        var index = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-index'));
        self.numbers()[index] = newVal;
        self.updateSum();
    }

    self.sum = ko.observable(0);

    self.updateSum = function() {
        var items = self.numbers();
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(items[i]);
        }
        self.sum(total);
    };

    self.updateSum();

    self.add = function() {
        var lastIndex = self.numbers().length - 1;
        var lastValue = self.numbers()[lastIndex];
        self.numbers.push(lastValue + 1);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: While this seems to work with IE11, the sum in the jsfiddle example does not update on changes of the values in the text field in Firefox 45.0.1